# Ajax update table data but not to repeat theader

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have table data being updated by jQuery AJAX call but I only want to create table header once if not created before.

So after the first ajax update I have the table header created first then data row appended to tbody which is fine,

but on the second update it keeps adding the theader although I check length of theader before I create one, but length always returns 0 as the result the theader keep adding along with table data, any idea what am I doing wrong? Sorry my learning curve.

### jQuery:

```
success: function(response){                            
    $.each(response, function (index, file) {
        var newFileRow; 
        var tableHeader = '<tr id="fileTblHeaderRow">' +
                            '<th> <span>Name</span> </th>' + 
                            '<th> <span>Size</span> </th>' +                                                    
                            '</tr>';                                                
        if($("fileTblHeaderRow").length) {                  
                            newFileRow = '<TR>' +
                            '<TD> <SPAN>' +file.name + '</SPAN> </TD>' +                                                    
                            '<TD> <SPAN>' +file.size + '</SPAN> </TD>' +                                                    
                            '</TR> <br />';
        } else {
            newFileRow = tableHeader +'<TR>' +
                            '<TD> <SPAN>' +file.name + '</SPAN> </TD>' +                                                    
                            '<TD> <SPAN>' +file.size + '</SPAN> </TD>' +                                                    
                            '</TR> <br />';
        }                               
        $('#fileListTblID').append(newFileRow);                                                                                     
    });  
},
```

Comment: Right now you're looking for the length of all <fileTblHeaderRow> elements, which of course you won't have - and will always equal 0. You need to indicate that this is the ID of the element like: $("#fileTblHeaderRow").length

Comment: Yup - that was it. didn't pay attention to it. my bad! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a hash prefix to select by ID:

```
if($("#fileTblHeaderRow").length)
```

Comment: God bless you - my friend! that was the problem and helped!